# How can I change the background image of a fixed top menu when a user scroll the site to some height

Tags: jquery

I am a newbie. Its my first question here. Forgive if I missed something.

I am looking to change the background image of a fixed menu div when a user scroll down to some height and when he scroll up again the first background image appears.

I have achieved this so far but I am not good in JavaScript so the issue is still there. Here is a demo of what I did so far:

Here!

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post your code here? and what you have already tried to do? People behind a firewall may not be able see the images/links you post

Comment: No code no way :) (not at least with your 1st message)

Comment: Sorry to miss the link to [JFiddle-Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QBwYr/). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For example using [skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr)

```
<div class="menu" data-0="background-image:!url(a.jpg);" data-500="background-image:!url(b.jpg);"></div>
```

Will change the background when scrolling down 500px and change it back when scrolling up again.

Comment: Thanks Prinzhorn! You gave me something new to learn. I implement your solution and it is working. Great! But I try to avoid using too many frameworks :). Is not it possible to do the jQuery way I did in my JFiddle example? Once again Thanks for your suggestion. You made my day :)